# IOS 5 grade book app set up

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a grade book app for teachers and I am on the last section of the app. I am creating the assignments portion. The app is set up where I create a course which is created in the form of a checklist for attendance taking purposes and then each student is an item in the checklist. I want to set up the assignments so that when creating or editing the course the user can add assignments to a tableview that will then be visible and accessible from the edit/add student page.

The current setup of the assignments tableview is that each cell will display the name of the assignment and the score of the individual student. If the user were to select a cell the tableview would then transition to the edit assignment page where there are simply two editable text fields, one for the assignment name and the other for the score.

Basically I am really unsure how to set this up. I have really been struggling with how to set up the "add" button on the assignment tableview and the cell for row at index path function in the assignment view controller specifically. Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new assignment, just add a new object to your tableView's source array and reload the table. So if in your `numbersOfRowsForSection` you have something like `return [arrayOfAssignments count];`, create an add method like so:

```
-(IBAction)addButtonPressed
{
    [arrayOfAssignements addObject:someAssignmentObject];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and that will refresh your table. You can add a + button anywhere and link up the selector in IB.

Comment: how would I go about the creation of a new object?